# SO FAQ update/modification on OpenID to include Internet Drivers License link

Tags: discussion

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html should be added to the FAQ

> **Do I have to log in or create an account?**
>
> Nope. You can answer and ask questions to your heart's content as an anonymous user, much like Wikipedia. However, there are some things you won't be able to do on the site without registering. But it's [easy to register](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) if you want to. All you need is an [OpenID](http://openid.net/what/).

change to: (suggestion #1)

> **Do I have to log in or create an account?**
>
> Nope. You can answer and ask questions to your heart's content as an anonymous user, much like Wikipedia. However, there are some things you won't be able to do on the site without registering. But it's [easy to register](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) if you want to. [All you need](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html) is an [OpenID](http://openid.net/what/).

I realize it's not a big change, but I think some people would appreciate knowing what an OpenID is and his blogpost was a pretty damned good excerpt on them.